# Set a value across all Hashes in an Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a ruby Array full of Hashes. I want to set a specific value for each item to the same value. For example, if I have an Array of Cars (Hash) and each car has a key of wheels. How do I set all the wheels to "square"?

I'm trying array.each.wheel = "square", but it's not working.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each

Comment: This is an odd expression, 'array.each.wheel'. I'd recommend looking at the 'each' method.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
array = [ {:wheel => "circle"}, {:wheel => "circle"}]
p array
array.each { |dictionary| dictionary[:wheel] = "square"}
p array
```

Output:

```
[{:wheel=>"circle"}, {:wheel=>"circle"}]
[{:wheel=>"square"}, {:wheel=>"square"}]
```